# How do I specify the expected result of a `std::ops::Mul` in a trait bound?

Tags: generics, rust, operator-overloading, traits

I have:

```
use std::ops::{Add, Div, Mul, Neg, Sub};

pub trait Hilbert: Add + Sub + Mul + Div + Neg + Mul<f64> + Div<f64> + Sized {
    fn dot(&self, other: &Self) -> f64;
    fn magnitude(&self) -> f64;
}

fn g<T: Hilbert>(x: T) -> f64 {
    return (x * 2.0).dot(x);
}
```

...which yields:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `dot` found for type `<T as std::ops::Mul<f64>>::Output` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:22
  |
9 |     return (x * 2.0).dot(x);
  |                      ^^^
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
  = note: the following trait defines an item `dot`, perhaps you need to implement it:
          candidate #1: `Hilbert`
```

I interpret this to mean that Rust can't guarantee that the type `T`, which has trait `Hilbert`, has an implementation of `std::ops::Mul` whose `::Output` type is equal to `T` (a `Hilbert`).

But I know (and / or wish to demand) that this is the case for all `Hilbert`s, so that functions like `g()` are possible to write.

I would think to impl `std::ops::Mul::Output` for `Hilbert`:

```
impl<T: Hilbert> Mul<f64> for T {
    type Output = T;
}
```

...but this has the simultaneous problems that (a) I can't "partially implement" a trait, and would be forced to produce a generic implementation of the function `Mul::mul()` for all `Hilberts`, but the actual implementation of `Mul::mul()` will depend on the specific implementation of `Hilbert`; and (b) it seems I am not allowed to write this trait at all:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`); only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
  --> src/main.rs:12:1
   |
12 | / impl<T: Hilbert> Mul<f64> for T {
13 | |     type Output = T;
14 | | }
   | |_^
```

How do I persuade Rust that `Hilbert` * `f64` -> `Hilbert` must hold?

Comment: While preparing an answer, I realized that  your question is somewhat ambiguous. Is there going to be only one implementation of `Hilbert` or will different implementations interact with each other? In other words, shold it be possible to do `a.dot(a)` , where `a` and `b` are different *implementations* of `Hilbert`, or do they have to be different *instances of the same implementation*?

Comment: @kazemakase My intent was that `Hilbert`s only need to interact with their own type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I persuade Rust that `Hilbert * f64` -> `Hilbert` must hold?

You add a trait bound `<T as Mul<f64>>::Output: Hilbert`. However, doing so will reveal further issues in your design:

1. `Hilbert.dot()` takes the second argument as reference, not by value. But changing the relevant line to `(x * 2.0).dot(&x)` leads to another error: *"expected associated type, found type parameter"*.
2. This one is because you defined `dot` to take `Self`, but there could be different implementations of `Hilbert` you want to multiply. `dot` needs to be generic: `fn dot<H: Hilbert>(&self, other: &H) -> f64;`
3. Finally, the borrow checker hits: `(x * 2.0).dot(&x)` won't let you use `x` twice, because `mul` takes its argument by value. You will either have to add a bound `Mul<&'a Self>` to be able to pass in a reference (which infects your API with lifetime parameters) or make `x` cloneable (I don't think copyable would apply).

Applying all of the above results in this <s>working(?)</s> compilable code:

```
pub trait Hilbert: Add + Sub + Mul + Div + Neg + Mul<f64> + Div<f64> + Sized {
    fn dot<H: Hilbert>(&self, other: &H) -> f64;
    fn magnitude(&self) -> f64;
}

fn g<T: Hilbert + Clone>(x: T) -> f64
where
    <T as Mul<f64>>::Output: Hilbert,
{
    (x.clone() * 2.0).dot(&x)
}
```

If `Hilbert.dot` should not be generic because different implementations of `Hilbert` do not need to interact, the code can be slightly simpler (in terms of trait bounds):

```
pub trait Hilbert:
    Add + Sub + Mul + Div + Neg + Mul<f64, Output = Self> + Div<f64, Output = Self> + Sized
{
    fn dot(&self, other: &Self) -> f64;
    fn magnitude(&self) -> f64;
}

fn g<T: Hilbert + Clone>(x: T) -> f64 {
    (x.clone() * 2.0).dot(&x)
}
```

However, from what I know about the Hilbert transform, this latter case seems unlikely to be useful.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick! ([Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) is the intended concept ;)

Comment: @trbabb In that case the simpler second approach would be useful, I suppose :)